Microsoft Identity Manager - Sync of multiple user profiles service
We have installed the MIM tool to synchronize SharePoint user profiles from Active Directory (SP 2016 On-premises). We use it in particular to automate the synchronization of user photos, which is impossible with standard AD Import synchronization without powershell script automation.
Unfortunately, we're having trouble getting the synchronization to work as we'd hoped.  I'd like to explain what we need, and hope that one of you will be able to confirm its feasibility, or even help us correct the problem.
In SharePoint, we have several userprofiles in place. We want to populate these services with user accounts in different OU ADs. We have users present in different OUs, classified by country for example

FR for France
IT for Italy
...

To separate synchronization, in MIM and in UserProfiles, we've created several management agents (sharepoint and AD). 1x sharepoint management per userprofile service and 1x ad management filtered by OU/container. In this way, we hope to be able to synchronize only OU-specific AD users in a specific sharepoint user service.
Today, I have doubts about the feasibility of this approach, as I can't manage to synchronize the data. Before analyzing my synchronization problems in depth, I'd like to know whether you think this approach is feasible?
Thank you in advance for your help.
Have a nice day,
